# Android Studio 3.4/Gradle v5 Update Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I updated my version of Android Studio to 3.4, it then asked me to upgrade Gradle to v5.1.1 from v4.10.1.

However the gradle project sync keeps failing now:

> ERROR: Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;'.
>
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
>   a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping
>   all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible
>   with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle
>   requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
>   IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've tried all of those options but I'm still getting the same error. I found the below information about upgrading from v4 to v5:

> The classesDir property has been removed from both the JDepend task
>   and SourceSetOutput. Use the JDepend.classesDirs and
>   SourceSetOutput.classesDirs properties instead.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

The only useful information it provides it to use the properties mentioned instead. But I don't know what I need to be replacing, I can't see `SourceSetOutput` being used anywhere in my code. I don't suppose anyone else has come across this or knows how to fix this issue?

I have also tried upgrading to the latest Gradle version which is 5.4.1 but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: "I can't see SourceSetOutput being used anywhere in my code" -- you should be looking for `classesDir`.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate Android Studio's cache and restart it?

Comment: I also looked for classesDir but I couldn't see that either.

Comment: I've also tried to invalidate the cache and restart but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just update Android Studio to 3.4 stable version. This is working for me :)

Comment: I did update to Android Studio 3.4, that's when it asked me to update gradle to v5 and that's when I started getting the error.

Comment: Java version should be 1.8 or above, update java and check once.

Comment: Java version is 1.8.0_202 so it shouldn't be that